# Spring Boot Actuator - enable single endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

There's a difference in implementation between two versions of Spring Boot Actuator (1.2.5 and 1.3.0) in HealthMvcEndpoint, isUnrestricted() method ( && and || ). I understand that this is to preserve these restrictions

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-health-access-restrictions

But is there any solution now to enable only one endpoint (e.g. Health) unrestricted with full content, without exposing all the others?
Disabling management.security.enabled is just making all the endpoints accessible without authentication (?) - it doesn't look like it's taking endpoint sensitivity with it.

Comment: Do you want to disable all but one endpoint, or do you want to have them all enabled but allow unrestricted access to a single endpoint?

Comment: I was wondering if it's possible to preserve original behaviour of the endpoints and to make a single one of them available in unrestricted access. I can just override HealthMvcEndpoint, but that won't be the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to partially solve this by making all the endpoints disabled in the first place by `endpoints.enabled = false` with disabling their security `management.security.enabled = false` 
and enabled the ones I wanted without security - like the Health endpoint
`endpoints.health.enabled = true` and `endpoints.health.sensitive = false`.

Answer (score 1):

With actuator 2 these properties have been changed

To **disable** all the actuator endpoints use

```
management.endpoints.enabled-by-default=false
```

To enable specific endpoint use `management.endpoint.<id>.enabled` property. The following example enables the shutdown endpoint:

```
management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true
```

**Official Documentation**

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html

Comment: Additionally I needed to expose the endpoints with e.g. `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=shutdown`.